# coldfusion class path for multiple services - only recognizing first directory

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to use multiple web services on a single CF page.  I have entered the stubs directory for each of the web services in the ColdFusion Class Path within administrator > server settings > java and jvm

paths are listed separated by commas:  c:\coldfusion9\stubs\ws1,c:\coldfusion9\stubs\ws2

for some reason, only the web service whose stub path is listed first will work.  When I try to call the second web service, I get a "web service operation ... cannot be found"

but if i switch the order of paths listed in the admin settings and restart the service, the web service listed first now will work.

any ideas on how to manage multiple web services and their stubs ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are also the owner of services, method proposed by Adam in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119721/duplicate-file-name-for-same-wsdl-namespace-when-using-web-service-from-differe/1126143#1126143) can possibly help you too.

Comment: no, this doesn't address the problem, which is adding 2 directories of stubs to the classpath.  i am already accessing the WSDL fine, and it is generating the stubs fine, but when i add two paths it is only acknowledging the first

Comment: I see, but it looks like local CF is trying to re-use the same stub for different services. Reason can be in the same name of the targetNamespace -- like for me with same webservice on different domains.